# Firebase site - Hosted or Storage for site assets?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I have a small firebase project site that I've been working on and is now public and gaining more traction than I thought. I doubt I'll hit Firebase's 10GB hosting transfer cap, but this got me thinking as to whether or not I'd be better served storing my site assets in Firebase Storage, and if that would help at all. I'm a bit new to these cloud service pricing models, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Boiling it down, here are my questions:

I have 20mb of assets currently stored in a /rsc/ directory on my hosted site. Would it lessen my Hosting "Data Transferred" to move these assets to Firebase Storage (Would the data transferred be logged under my Storage quota)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you put the files in Cloud Storage instead those will not be counted against the Firebase Hosting bandwidth limits. However, you will lose out on the global CDN edge-caching and atomic rollout/rollback provided by Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Gotcha. I figured the rollout would be a bit more involved but forgot about the CDN. I made some changes to the site to defer render and loading of the majority of these assets until they're needed, and it seems to be stemming the flood, so the move will not be required (hopefully), but the information is good to have anyways. Thanks!